# What's some examples of the fact disjoint events are dependent?

Tags: probability

Disjoint events A and B with positive probability must not be independent as $P(A)$, $P(B) \gt 0$, $P(A\cap B) = P(\emptyset) = 0 \Rightarrow P(A\cap B) \lt P(A)P(B)$.  What are some real world examples that can help better understanding this?

Comment: Consider the experiment of rolling a fair dice and define $A=\{\text{roll a }1,\text{ or a } 2, \text{ or a } 3\}$, $B=\{\text{roll a } 4,\text{ or a } 5, \text{ or a } 6\}$. Clearly, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $P(A)=P(B)=1/2 \gt 0$, which satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Consider any attribute which is normally regarded as categorical (eye color, sex, educational level). Any of them work - e.g. if I have blue eyes, *even though brown eyes are very common, I* ***know*** *I don't have brown eyes* - not-having-brown-eyes is utterly dependent on having-blue-eyes.

Comment: @Procrastinator  Excuse me, but it is not obvious to me that $A$ and $B$ are dependent.

Comment: @Glen_b, $A$ and $B$ being "having blue eye" and "having brown eye", shouldn't you be making a statement on those?  Why you said something about $A$ and $B^c$?  In other words, it is still not obvious to me that "having blue eye" and "having brown eye" are dependent.

Comment: By [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_events) of independent events. You can see that this is not satisfied. Intuitively, if $A$ occurs, then $B$ cannot occur. This reflects the dependency.

Comment: @user6076 If your eyes are brown, they aren't blue. If your eyes are blue, they aren't brown. If one occurs, the other doesn't. The probability of occurrence of one depends on whether or not the other has occurred.

Comment: Paraphrasing Procrastinator and Glen_b: $A$ contains some information about $B$, since we know that $B$ cannot occur when $A$ occur ($P(B\mid A) = 0$)

Comment: Could one of you move your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any attribute which is normally regarded as categorical (eye color, sex, educational level). Any of them work - e.g. if I have blue eyes, *even though brown eyes are very common, I* ***know*** *I don't have brown eyes* - not-having-brown-eyes is utterly dependent on having-blue-eyes.

[If your eyes are brown, they aren't blue.* If your eyes are blue, they aren't brown. If one occurs, the other doesn't.]

* Note that "one blue and one brown eye" is *neither* "having brown eyes" nor "having blue eyes".